# SQL Presto Aggregate Table column values with another column values

Tags: sql, presto

Hi I want to do SQL Presto query for the data table (say **user_data**) looks like

```
user | target | result
-----------------------------
 1   |    b   | {A: 1}
 2   |    a   | {C: 2}
 1   |    c   | {A: 2, B: 3}
 2   |    d   | {A: 1}
 1   |    d   | {C: 4}
```

With this data table, I would like to generate the following two outputs.

**Output 1:** Count the number of unique targets for each result for each user. For example, for user 1, this user has 2 targets (b and c) who have result A. And it has one target for each result B (target c) and C (target d).

```
user | result
-------------------
  1  | {A: 2, B:1, C:1}
  2  | {A: 1, C: 1}
```

**Output 2:** Aggregate the last column based on the targets of the user.

```
user | result
-------------------
  1  | {A:[b,c], B:[c], C:[d]}
  2  | {A:[d], C:[a]}
```

** Or Even better, can we make a one table that has both columns?

```
user |     result 1         |   result 2
--------------------------------------------------
  1  | {A:[b,c], B:[c], C:[d]} | {A: 2, B:1, C:1}
  2  | {A:[d], C:[a]}          | {A: 1, C: 1}
```

Can anyone help me with it? I would really appreciate it.

I'm pretty new to SQL so I didn't even know how to start it.`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with [`map` aggregate functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#map-aggregate-functions). Assuming that `result` originally is a `map` you can flatten it with [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) and then group by `user` and use `multimap_agg` and `histogram` functions:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(user, target, result) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'b', map(array['A'], array[1])),
        (2, 'a', map(array['C'], array[2])),
        (1, 'c', map(array['A', 'B'], array[2, 3])),
        (2, 'd', map(array['A'], array[1])),
        (1, 'd', map(array['C'], array[4]))
)

-- query
select user, multimap_agg(k, target), histogram(k)
from dataset,
unnest(result) as t(k, v)
group by user;
```

Output:

| user | _col1 | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | {A=[d], C=[a]} | {A=1, C=1} |
| 1 | {A=[b, c], B=[c], C=[d]} | {A=2, B=1, C=1} |